# Flutter Multi-Threading Issue when uploading multiple url gifs/images

Tags: multithreading, http, flutter, giphy

I'm consistently receiving multi-threading issues when downloading a list of gifs from giphy.com.  Each time my app crashes and logs a "I/Choreographer(15955): Skipped 104 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread." type error.  I haven't come across any threading solutions for flutter.  Here is my code...

```
 Future<Null> giphy() async {
    var _searchterm = _searchController.text.toString().replaceAll(' ', '+');
    String url = GIPHY.com;

    //var httpClient = createHttpClient();
    var response = await http.get(url);
    Map data = json.decode(response.body);
    //print(data['data']);
    var gifs = new List();
    for (var items in data['data']) {
      var images = (items['images'] as Map);
      var downsized = (images['downsized'] as Map);
      var urls = downsized['url'].toString();
      gifs.add(urls);
    }

    setState(() => giphyUrls = gifs);
    _neverSatisfied();
  }
```

`giphyUrls` is a public list that feeds into a gridview builder.

Comment: How often is `giphy()` called?

Comment: `"threading overload" type error`. Please post the exact and full error output.

Comment: giphy() is called once.  Loading app now to reproduce error...

Comment: `I/Choreographer(15955): Skipped 104 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.`

Comment: You might want to move the code to another Dart isolate.

Comment: You mean another file?

Comment: https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-isolate/dart-isolate-library.html Isolates run in another thread.